# How to acces AzureRM with a AzureAD Multi-Tenant App using personal Microsoft account?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

My target is simple: use an Azure AD multi-tenant app to be able to call Azure Resource Manager API on other tenants. However, I cannot figure out how to do it when you sign in with a personal Microsoft account.

1. I created an Azure AD multi-tenant app using a company's tenant
   [image]
2. Then created a test ASP.NET Core Web application which goes to a such URL:
   [image]
3. The Microsoft's login page shows up and I'm able to log in successfully with a **personal LIVE.COM**, where the test Web app receives the callback with given redirect URL. I have another Azure tenant created with my personal MS account which I'm trying to access.
4. The Multi-Tenant AAD App gets added to the "personal space" at https://account.live.com/consent/Manage, but not to the Azure AD tenant.
   [image]

It probably makes sense from the technical standpoint, but how do I add the AAD app to another tenant when logged in with a personal account?

I figured that the "authorize" URL must include the AAD tenant name/ID instead of "common" (confirm that a Service Principal gets created on the target tenant):
[image]
However, that tenant name/ID is unknown when a user logs in, and I don't really know what API to use to query it.

Should be done by hand - detecting a personal MS account and finding the association with AAD tenant, or is there an API that can facilitate this? In both cases, how? What if an account is associated with multiple tenants ("Switch Directory" in Azure Portal)?

P.S. using URLs `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` ("orgainzations" instead of "common") or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` (without "v2.0") won't allow using a personal MS account to log in.

---

**UPDATE**

To demonstrate the problem, there are 4 tests were made to access resource "https://management.azure.com/" with a multi-tenant app:

1. Authorize Microsoft's "Microsoft Azure" app with v1 endpoint - it works with personal accounts:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&resource=https://management.azure.com/&nonce=123&state=common&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64696%2FAuthCallback
2. Authorize the same "Microsoft Azure" app with v2 endpoint - now it does not allow to use personal accounts:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default&nonce=123&state=common&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64696%2FAuthCallback
3. Authorize a custom multitenant app against v1 endpoint (insert your client id) - shows error AADSTS50020 "User account 'user@live.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'contoso.com' and cannot access the application ''(app name) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&resource=https://management.azure.com/&nonce=123&state=common&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64696%2FAuthCallback
4. Authorize a custom multitenant app against v2 endpoint - same as test #2 - does not allow personal accounts.

**Thoughts.**

1. The v2 endpoint does not allow personal accounts for the resource https://management.azure.com/, where the v1 endpoint does.
2. Microsoft Azure app probably has a manifest with undocumented or hardcoded settings that allows to use personal accounts for the desired resource.

---

**ANSWER**

Long story short, it's not possible for general public as per Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only V2.0 endpoint supports personal account(even it doesn't belong to any Azure AD tenants) to login.**

[image]

> It works with personal account when you use v1.0 endpoint.

That's because that personal account belongs to at least one Azure AD tenant. Then this personal account will be recognized as a guest user in the tenant.

> The v2 endpoint does not allow personal accounts for the resource
>   https://management.azure.com/

Yes, if you login in with personal account when you use v2.0 endpoint, it will detect that you belong to personal account and will redirect you to the personal account login endpoint `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf`.

You must identify the tenant to login in with personal account when use v2.0 endpoint

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=20244877-ae8f-4325-b4cf-c6dc239cb124
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&state=12345
&nonce=default
```

Then you can call `https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01` to list all the tenants that account belongs to.

**Update:**

> It is normal that you can't do that. You are not telling Azure AD that
>   the which tenant the MSA user is an external user, so Azure AD is
>   making a guess and checking in the tenant where the app is registered
>   (tenant A). If you expect external users to be able to sign in, you
>   must specify the tenant where the guest has previously been invited to
>   (e.g. tenant B).

Comment: Thanks, but this is a chicken and an egg problem: 1. `You must identify the tenant to login in with personal account`; 2. `Then you can list all the tenants`. This is not how Azure Portal or Microsoft's API Docs 'Try It' work. You log in with your personal account without specifying any tenant, then you can select a tenant if you have multiple.

Comment: Imagine the user experience: your website has 2 buttons - log in with work account and log in with a personal account, where if you log in with a personal account you have to type in a mystical tenant ID.

Comment: I traced API requests for `Connect-AzureRmAccount` (PowerShell) with Fiddler, and confirm that Microsoft uses V1 endpoint and set `Common` for the `{tenantId}`. There is something special about their application manifest that allows a personal account to work - the link in question's test 1 works and link in test 3 does not. I'm trying to find what that secret is.

Comment: @SergeSemenov If you can confirm that the personal account has at least one tenant, you can use v1.0 endpoint to list the tenants, just like Powershell does. It will not recognize the `personal account` as personal account, it will recognize it as guest user in tenant. I have explained in the answer why test 1 works and test 3 doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I do confirm. I've had a personal account with 2 tenants for 5 years,  and I even created a new hotmail account with new azure tenant a week ago to double check.

Comment: @SergeSemenov Sorry, I am a little confused. Are you saying that your personal account has tenants but can not login with it when using v1.0 endpoint?

Comment: @SergeSemenov Can you login in with your personal account here? 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=97bfde0f-e054-4d80-8c39-fafd115599b4
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://management.azure.com/
&state=12345

Comment: That's correct, I use v1 endpoint, try to login with a personal account that has tenant(s) and it fails with an error described in test 3. Tried your link - also fails with a slightly different error:

Comment: `AADSTS500011: The resource principal named management.azure.com was not found in the tenant named e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.`

Comment: Ah, the link provided is incorrect. Here is the right one: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=97bfde0f-e054-4d80-8c39-fafd115599b4&response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&resource=https://management.azure.com/&nonce=123&state=common&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64696%2FAuthCallback

Comment: And still fails like test 3: `AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxxx@live.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Devchat' and cannot access the application '97bfde0f-e054-4d80-8c39-fafd115599b4'(tonyTestMultiTenant) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.`

Comment: @SergeSemenov I have confirmed this with Microsoft Azure Engineer, see the updates in the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @tony-ju, that's what suspected - Microsoft's internal apps have a secret way that allows them to work as desired. Did the engineer say if it's going to be available to public any soon?

Comment: thank you again for helping, could you point me to the right resource where I can submit a feature request for this particular issue? Is it on UserVoice?

Comment: @SergeSemenov You can submit a feedback here. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback