# Multi-Tenant Azure Active Directory application with Msal for Angular 6

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-msal

We are developing a SPA (Single page application) that any user with a valid Azure account can use. The app uses permissions such as Azure Resource Management (user_impersonation) for showing statistics and monitoring some Azure resources.

The application is built with Angualr 6+ and we are using the latest version of [Msal-Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/master/lib/msal-angular) for authentication. (the rxjs-compact package is installed for supporting angualr 6+)

I've already registered an App Registration in Azure (multi-tenant) with the configured permissions, but I'm having trouble configuring Msal-Angular for supporting Multi-Tenancy.

Our configuration works for organizational users but not for personal accounts that are not in my Active Directory.

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  clientID: environment.aadClientId,
  redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/',

  protectedResourceMap: [['https://management.azure.com/', ['https://management.azure.com/.default']]]
})
```

If I try to change the authority to 'common' as in the following:

> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/'

The login works, but the scopes are not acquired correctly and any attempt to access a secure API such as 'https://management.azure.com/' yields the following error:

> ERROR The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://management.azure.com/.default openid profile' does not exist.|invalid_scope

Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible to implement with Msal-Angular or should I use Msal Core?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @TonyJu Sorry about the delay in my response. I've added a comment (question) to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow personal account to login, you need to use common endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`.

And the supported account type must be "**Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**"

[image]

**However:**  `https://management.azure.com` api is not supported when you use `common` endpoint and personal accounts. You can only use multi-tenant users here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry about the delay in mine! I have a question- if "https://management.azure.com" doesn't support personal accounts, then there isn't any way to achieve what I need? Let's assume that I'm developing a tool like 'Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer' but for Azure Functions, and I want to target both personal and organization accounts with Azure Active Directory (as Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer does). Is it possible? What are my options?

Comment: If 'https://management.azure.com' isn't supported then which permissions the Azure Portal uses to authenticate personal accounts?

Comment: @m1o2 This is by design, portal and powershell can do that. I have talked this with Azure support engineer.  See my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57885541/10504999

Comment: I've marked it as the answer. Thanks for your help. The link to your answer was really helpful.